# Defining cv::Mat in header followed by another Mat avoids multiple channels

Tags: c++, memory-management, opencv

i've just encountered a strange problem. In the header of my class I have defined multiple `cv::Mat` like this:
`cv::Mat drawing, img_grad, img_bright, img_cov;`   (ver1)
`cv::Mat drawing, img_grad, img_bright, img_cov, img_notused;` (ver2)

In the code i then define img_cov as the following:
`img_cov = Mat::zeros( somemat.size(), CV_32FC(6) )`
Strange thing is that if i add another Mat to the header declaration (see ver2 above) of my multiple Mats that, even if `img_notused` it is never used, i am not able to access any other channel of my `img_cov` than 0. Accessing e.g. via `img_cov.at<float>( j, i, 1)` leads to a crash.

Seems to be a mermoy-allocation thing. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a wrong command to access the image values (it should have crashed earlier on, maybe you compile in release mode...).

Your line should look like this:

```
typedef Vec<6,float> Vec6f;
Vec6f pixel = img_cov.at<Vec6f>(i,j); 
float value_you_look_for = pixel[1]; // note that 1 means the second channel of 6.
```

because `CV_32FC(6)` means a 6-channel matrix with `float` values in the channels.

For your reference: [link to specific docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values)

Comment: Thanks, but the way I wrote it in my first post truly delivers wrong results but why does it return results at all given i do not declare any other Mat in the header after the one accessed? Sadly i did not put the `<float>` in code marks, that's why the site did not display it this way. Whatever, the accessing of the values your way works with "Ver1" as well as "Ver2". But does this explain the strange behavior mentioned above?

Comment: My way works with Ver1 and Ver2 because it is correct. Your way worked just by chance. Probably the compiler delivers different memory layout depending on the number of variables and you are closer to the boundary of the limit of the allocated memory, initially. Still, the values returned will be wrong in your Ver1 and Ver2, try and display it.

Comment: Yeah, they are truly totally wrong and very very small. Strange, somewhere i red about the `img_cov.at<float>( j, i, 1)`-command but obviously that was a wrong trail. Thanks!